# Why does allowDiskUse not working in aggregation pipeline for $group stage?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I was working on an aggregation pipeline to cleanup duplicate data from a collection on the database. But it was throwing the following error even after setting `{ allowDiskUse: true }`.

`Err: "MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external spilling; pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in"`

The `objective` was to delete all duplicates (same phoneNumber with same startTime) after retaining the first entry from the database.

Below is my pipeline:

```
let pipeline = [
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                phoneNumber: "$details.phoneNumber",
                startTime: "$details.startTime",
            },
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
            count: { $sum: 1 },
        },
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: { $gt: 1 },
        },
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$docs",
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "docs.createdAt": 1,
        },
    },
    {
        $skip: 1,
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$docs" },
    },
]
```

Here, while calling aggregate, i passed in "allowDiskUse" as mentioned in the types as below, but still it's throwing the same error.

This is how i added the option:

```
const options = {
    allowDiskUse: true,
    maxTimeMS: 10000,
}
```

And then using mongodb node driver `v5.8`, i used aggregation operation like below:

```
db.collection(collectionName).aggregate(pipeline, options)
```

Here, i added allowDiskUse like the error message suggested, but still it's not working. Even in mongodb compass its throwing the same error.

[image: compass error]

So, what's the issue here?

And if i could do my objective in any other way, please comment.

Thanks

Comment: this can be an heavy operation, but this query can be optimized. No need to push all the `$$ROOT`s and no need to `$unwind`. Use `$first` instead

Comment: Are you running on a shared cluster on Atlas (M0, M2, M5)? There is a limitation for these that `allowDiskUse` cannot be activated on shared hardware.https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/free-shared-limitations/#operational-limits

Comment: @nimrodserok does it solve my purpose of retaining first one and discarding all others?

Comment: @Markus it was indeed the issue, i was running it on a shared cluster to test, before running it on production db which is on m10.

Comment: If you provide some sample data and requested result from it. I'll show you

Comment: @nimrodserok here is the sample data, i've only kept very minimal. https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.db4750940fb64f7ab03580c8c959693e

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you are not running on a MongoDB Atlas shared cluster (M0, M2, M5). For these, `allowDiskUse` cannot be enabled.

See this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/free-shared-limitations/#operational-limits) on the limitations of the shared clusters.

Comment: This is it. Accepting it as answer since i asked only abt this.
But is there a clear way to optimise and achieve what i was trying to do?
P.S: Need 2 more reps before i can upvote your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This one may work better:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         partitionBy: {
            phoneNumber: "$details.phoneNumber",
            startTime: "$details.startTime"
         },
         sortBy: { _id: 1 },
         output: {
            count: { $documentNumber: {} }
         }
      }
   },
   { $match: { count: 1 } }
])
```

Comment: This returns the first unique documents right, now how can we delete the others? All these time, i was trying to get all others and delete it.

Comment: Run a second command of `db.collection.deleteMany({count: {$gt: 1}})`. With `$setWindowFields` you cannot do it in a single command.

Comment: Note, an aggregation pipeline does not update your documents. Try `db.collection.updateMany({}, [...])` or you can run a loop over the result and update documents one by one or in bulk.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but what if we use a `$set` as next stage of the pipeline? Then we could update the documents that we get from the last stage right?

Comment: No, an `aggregate` does never update anything (unless you have a `$merge` or `$out` stage), it only select and display your data.